# how do you clear apple/mac install program files?

Tags: macos, installation, osx-snow-leopard, uninstall

I installed a 30-day "test drive" of QuarkXpress, but got pulled in to other projects and didn't have time to test it. I now need to test it, but the 30 days are up. So I want to install the "test drive" again, but it won't let me.
So far I uninstalled the old copy, signed up under a different account, and downloaded a new version. I know there has to be application data somewhere, but I am a PC person and don't know where to look in the Apple. HELP! Thanks.

Oh, and if necessary, I am using Mac OS X (SnowLeopard) Version 10.6.8 on a MacPro

Comment: Yea they usually hide bits on your computer somewhere hard to find so you can't just keep on installing the trial over and over again.

Comment: Try using AppDelete Or search within the directory ~Library/Application Support

Comment: @Brian ...put that up as an ANSWER rather than a comment, and I'll check that off since that's what I ended up doing! (shows how little I really know about Apple). And thanks!

Comment: @mserin Which comment did you mean? The one from @WhiteTiger? Also, you can easily answer the question yourself and be more specific about what exactly you had to delete.

Comment: Well I think Brian deleted his, but @WhiteTiger worked as well!